# Unable to set cookie for golang's fasthttp framework

Tags: fasthttp

I trying to set the cookie from the server using fasthttp framework. But the cookie value is not set properly in the response header. I don't know what I have missed in the below snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func main() {
    if err := fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8080", requestHandler); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error in ListenAndServe: %s", err)
    }
}

func requestHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    switch string(ctx.Path()) {
    case "/foo":
        cook1 := fasthttp.Cookie{}
        cook1.SetKey("cookie_key")
        cook1.SetValue("cookie val")
        cook1.SetMaxAge(3600000)
        cook1.SetDomain("prabhakaran.com")
        cook1.SetPath(("/"))
        cook1.SetSecure(true)
        ctx.Response.Header.Cookie(&cook1)
        ctx.SetBody([]byte("this is completely new body contents"))

    case "/bar":
        //todo: Bar handler
        // ctx.SetBody([]byte("111111111111111111111"))
    default:
        ctx.Error("Unsupported path", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
    }
}
```

I tried **ctx.Response.Header.SetCookie(&cook1)** API too. But it won't works. Is anything missed the snippet?

Comment: You should ask the author of fasthttp.

Comment: @Volker Yeah sure. fasthttp is one of the tag of stackoverflow. That's why I posted here.

Comment: Note that fasthttp is not a framework. It's just an HTTP library, tuned for high performance.

Comment: @Flimzy It is a library for a **subset** of HTTP.

Comment: @Volker: Yes, indeed. My point, though, was that it's not a framework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ctx.Response.Header.Cookie(&cook1)
```

The Cookie function is used for peek the cookie value. So, use **SetCookie** function instead of Cookie. If you are running the server in http protocol, remove the **cook1.SetSecure(true)** statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of cookie-retrieve

```golang
// ParseTokenFromRequest is delegated to retrieved the token encoded in the request. The token can be sent in two different way.
// In first instance the method will try to find the token in the cookie. If the cookie is not provided in the cookie,
// then the research will continue analayzing the body of the request (URL ARGS,GET,POST).
// In case of token not found, an empty string will be returned
func ParseTokenFromRequest(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) string {
    token := string(ctx.Request.Header.Cookie("GoLog-Token")) // GoLog-Token is the hardcoded name of the cookie
    log.Info("ParseTokenFromRequest | Checking if token is in the cookie ...")
    if strings.Compare(token, "") == 0 { // No cookie provided :/ Checking in the request
        log.Warn("ParseTokenFromRequest | Token is not in the cookie, retrieving from the request ...")
        token = string(ctx.FormValue("token")) // Extracting the token from the request (ARGS,GET,POST)
        if strings.Compare(token, "") == 0 {   // No token provided in the request
            log.Warn("ParseTokenFromRequest | Can not find the token! ...")
            return "" // "COOKIE_NOT_PRESENT"
        }
        log.Info("ParseTokenFromRequest | Token found in request! ... | ", token)
    } else {
        log.Info("ParseTokenFromRequest | Token found in cookie! ... | ", token)
    }
    return token
}
```

Here an example of cookie-set

```golang
//CreateCookie Method that return a cookie valorized as input (GoLog-Token as key)
func CreateCookie(key string, value string, expire int) *fasthttp.Cookie {
    if strings.Compare(key, "") == 0 {
        key = "GoLog-Token"
    }
    log.Debug("CreateCookie | Creating Cookie | Key: ", key, " | Val: ", value)
    authCookie := fasthttp.Cookie{}
    authCookie.SetKey(key)
    authCookie.SetValue(value)
    authCookie.SetMaxAge(expire)
    authCookie.SetHTTPOnly(true)
    authCookie.SetSameSite(fasthttp.CookieSameSiteLaxMode)
    return &authCookie
}
authcookie := CreateCookie('','TEST_VALUE',120)
ctx.Response.Header.SetCookie(authcookie)     // Set the token into the cookie headers
ctx.Response.Header.Set("GoLog-Token", token) // Set the token into a custom headers
```

Here an example of cookie-delete

```golang
ctx.Response.Header.DelCookie("GoLog-Token")
```